# Unify page style-sheets from version to version and compare overrides

Tags: css, stylesheet

New version (v2) of website required additional 3rd party style-sheets which disturbed layouts of few elements already defined in previous 3rd party style-sheets in version (v1). My question is:

- How to list all styles in various style-sheets in a specific version of page as **single unified normalized and sorted css file**. Like all-styles-indexhtml-v?.css, where ? = 1, 2 etc. New css file when replaced for all style-sheets in page should not affect rendered output.
- How can I find which styles in v2 overrides which style in v1.

Note: all style-sheets are 3rd party and internals not known

Comment: My knowledge of this is limited but I can suggest creating a test page with samples of most of the elements in your website used on your website - See (v1) style-sheet for reference. After doing that you can add all three (v2) stylesheets by using hard-coded links in your test page like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet1.css">` - `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet2.css">` - `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet3.css">` Whatever CSS selector comes last will overwrite anything that came before it.

Comment: That being said, I don't know how you can use 3rd party CSS without knowing the internals.

Comment: I wish to join all style-sheets as one file (already its like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet1.css">`, ... and should be like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="combined.css">`

Comment: These css are used by generator which converts markdown to page and uses css elements, so *as not manually applying css internals are not known*. My problem subset remains: how to join and find which styles are overridden where so that I can choose better style among two or more places it is used.

Comment: I see, well you can use online services like this one http://www.shrinker.ch/ You should however note that the process is automatic and you won't have much control over which selectors from which file will be chosen - I am sure the documentation for the tool would have such information. I should also note that your final merged css file will probably be bloated and have a lot of unused selectors. After linking the merged css file, make sure you try to locate unused selectors and delete them to reduce bandwidth wastage.

Comment: Yes I understand, that the problem remains to chose which style looks better for each element and to know which stylesheet it comes from. I would suggest creating three separate test pages, each one has as many of the elements that your website uses then loading one stylesheet on each of the pages. What comes after is visual examination and comparison. For example, you look at <h1> tags and how they render on all three different pages and chose the one you like most, then you mark it down - on papre? - that <h1> style in Stylesheet#2 is the best.... then you carry on like that the rest.

Comment: As to how you can select which elements from which stylesheet make it to the final merged stylesheet, I don't know if that's possible unless you manually edit the files and copy the selectors you like from each sheet into a new sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tool helps out in combining stylesheets in a page. Get it [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-remove-and-combine/cdfmaaeapjmacolkojefhfollmphonoh?hl=en-GB)